# Which Clearcase plugin to use for Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, clearcase

I have Clearcase Remote Client and Jenkins set up on my Windows machine. I am not sure which Clearcase plugin to use for connecting my CCRC with Jenkins. Is it the Clearcase plugin or Clearcase UCM plugin?

Answer (score 1):

The [Jenkins ClearCase plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Plugin) does mention:

> **This plugin doesn't support CCRC (Clearcase Remote Client), and probably never will**, given the large differences of implementation between this client and the full client.

The [Jenkins ClearCase UCM plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Plugin) uses `cleartool` as well, and is not compatible with CCRC.

That means on the slaves executing ClearCase tasks, you need a full ClearCase installation, not a CCRC client.